# Use a listcolumn to fill a combobox in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am using combo boxes quite a lot, and often i refer the rowsource in the properties like this `sheetx!tablename`

However, when i would like to use column 2 or as in the picture below called "Name"
i feel its annoying that i have to write a loop in the userform initialization to fill the combobox.

I was wondering and have been trying without success using listobject databydyrange listcolumn to fill
but no luck.

Now i wonder, Can i use a listobject column reference in the combobox rowsource?

Here is the code that gives me the error:

```
Worksheets("Engine").ListObjects("PeopleList").ListColumns("Name").Range.Select
```

[image]

Comment: things like this 
Worksheets("Engine").ListObjects("PeopleList").ListColumns("Name").Range.Select

but get a syntax eror when entering it into properties, most likely because i am trying to select, but i only need to reference.  (not sure how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a combobox `ListFillRange`:

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Sheet1!A2:A7"
```

A `ListColumn` has a `Range` so you can use its `Address` property:

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = Worksheets("Engine").ListObjects("PeopleList").ListColumns("Name").Range.Address
```

This will bring in the column header too so like you mentioned, you can use the `DataBodyRange` and us its `.Address` property instead.

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = Worksheets("Engine").ListObjects("PeopleList").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.Address
```

**EDIT**

As per comments, `.ListFillRange` exists on ActiveX form controls only, so for a UserForm ComboBox use `Rowsource`

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.RowSource = myRange
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the listcolum or table, because the range might change out of my control, and hardcoding a range is not really ideal.  

:D  But yes, the second part you wrote is currently my prefered solution.

Comment: I just updated my answer, because I realised you can use `DataBodyRange` like you mentioned, instead of a standard `Range` - that will take away the column header which I'm sure is better for a dropdownlist.

Comment: yeah, allready changed that.

Just trying to figure out why i am getting a "Compile erorr" on the .ListFillRange
Wondering if its a outdated method..

Comment: Ah, crap, listFillRange doesn't exist on UserForm combobox, that's my bad

Comment: Changed it to    .rowsource  then it works..

Cheers buddy.

Comment: Yeah I didn't read the question properly and tested it on an ActiveX control on a worksheet. Glad you figured it out!